# How to add a aggregate function where selected columns are within the same query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to include this following line of code to perform a calculation:

```
SUM((InitialTeamWeight / 10) * Form + InitialTeamWeight) AS FinalTeamWeight
```

But issue is that I can't call on the columns that are within the same SELECT Statement. I tried adding a sub query above this query that selects the above calculation but this performs a calculation for all the teams not individual teams.

What do I need to do in order to add the calculation into the query without having the issue of undefined columns?

Below is the current query:

```
SELECT TeamID,
    CASE WHEN TeamID = 0 THEN 0 
    ELSE SUM(po.playerWeighting)
    END TeamWeight
    --ABS(CHECKSUM(NewID())) % 10 + 1 AS Form
-- cte    
FROM(
        SELECT pl.*,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY pl.TeamID, pl.Position ORDER BY NEWID()) AS Rnk
-- cte        
        FROM(
            SELECT DISTINCT p.PlayerID, p.Position, p.PlayerWeighting, p.FirstName, p.Surname, t.TeamID, t.TeamAbbreviation, f.WeekNumber
            FROM dbo.Fixture f
            INNER JOIN dbo.League l ON f.LeagueID = l.LeagueID
            INNER JOIN dbo.Team t ON l.LeagueID = t.LeagueID
            INNER JOIN dbo.Player p ON t.TeamID = p.TeamID
            WHERE f.WeekNumber = 1) 
            pl) po 
    WHERE (po.Position = 'GK' and po.rnk = 1) OR 
          (po.Position = 'DF' and po.rnk <= 4) OR
          (po.Position = 'MF' and po.rnk <= 4) OR
          (po.Position = 'FW' and po.rnk <= 2)
          GROUP BY TeamID
```

Comment: This is not at all clear what the issue is. The title is about multiple ctes but you don't need them here...you don't have enough select statements here to have more than 1 cte. You could move the subquery to a cte but if this is already working it isn't going to make much difference. The execution plans will be the same.

Comment: @SeanLange I count 2 subqueries in there that could in theory be CTE'd, but you're right, the actual issue isn't clear. OP please add your table structure or better yet, provide an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @ChrisPickford I guess there is two in there. :)

Comment: I have changed my question to simply state how can I add the SUM into the query without having undefined columns issue

Comment: I would guess that you need to add those columns in your inner most query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not 100% clear what you're trying to do, but I am guessing that you have `TeamWeight` and now want to use that in your formula as `InitialTeamWeight`

I have added 2 CTE (which might help you with syntax for CTE) and removed the `CASE` from main query. Now `playerWeighting` is set to 0 if `TeamID` is 0 in CTE, which results in the same sum for `TeamId = 0`

```
WITH pl AS (SELECT DISTINCT p.PlayerID
                            p.Position
                            ,CASE WHEN p.TeamID = 0 THEN 0
                                  ELSE p.playerWeighting END AS playerWeighting
                            ,p.FirstName
                            ,p.Surname
                            ,t.TeamID
                            ,t.TeamAbbreviation
                            ,f.WeekNumber
            FROM dbo.Fixture f
            INNER JOIN dbo.League l ON f.LeagueID = l.LeagueID
            INNER JOIN dbo.Team t ON l.LeagueID = t.LeagueID
            INNER JOIN dbo.Player p ON t.TeamID = p.TeamID
            WHERE f.WeekNumber = 1)
,po AS (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY pl.TeamID, pl.Position ORDER BY NEWID()) AS Rnk FROM pl)
SELECT TeamID
    ,SUM(po.playerWeighting) AS TeamWeight
    ,SUM((SUM(po.playerWeighting) / 10) * Form + SUM(po.playerWeighting)) AS FinalTeamWeight
    --ABS(CHECKSUM(NewID())) % 10 + 1 AS Form
FROM po
WHERE (po.Position = 'GK' and po.rnk = 1) OR 
        (po.Position = 'DF' and po.rnk <= 4) OR
        (po.Position = 'MF' and po.rnk <= 4) OR
        (po.Position = 'FW' and po.rnk <= 2)
        GROUP BY TeamID
```

I'm not sure if this is what you needed but maybe it helps